# Define syntax in only one line

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression

I would like the first line of some documents I have to be highlighted as a comment.

I would like something like:

```
syntax match myTypeComment /{apply only to first line}^.*$/
```

But I don't know how this regex should work for only one line (e.g. the first line) in syntax matching.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `\%1l`; this will match a specific line.

For example, to highlight the first line if it starts with `# Hello`:

```
:syntax match myTypeComment /\%1l# Hello.*/
:hi myTypeComment ctermfg=red
```

This also works for other lines (e.g. `\%42l` for the 42nd line) and you can use `\%42<l` and `\%42>l` for lines before or after the 42nd line.

Also see [`:help /\%l`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%25l).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\%l` regex atom to make sure to match at a particular line. 
So you would likely want something along the lines of this:

```
:syntax match myTypeComment /^\%1l#.*/
```

See also the help at `:h /\%l`